# How to correctly debug Angular Application using chrome

Tags: angular, spring-boot, google-chrome, debugging

I developed an Application with Angular as the Front-end framework and SpringBoot as the Back-end.My task was to display the data passed from the Rest API on the browser.Every thing works fine but I'm stuck at the debugging process.

EmployeeController

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/restApi/app")
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeRepository.findAll();

    }
```

EmployeeComponent

```
import { EmployeeDetailsComponent } from './../employee-details/employee-details.component';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { EmployeeService } from "./../employee.service";
import { Employee } from "./../employee";
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {

    employees: Observable<Employee[]>;

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService,
    private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    
    this.reloadData();
  }

  reloadData() {
    this.employees = this.employeeService.getEmployeesList();
 console.log(this.employees);
  }
```

Output in the web page (It is shown as expected)
[image: output]

The data passed from the API is as follows when searched in the web browser as "http://localhost:8080/springboot/restApi/app/employees"
[image: Tha data passed from the back-end]

But when I'm trying to debug that data using the chrome browser it shows nothing passed to the variable employees.

[image: Result in debugging in chrome]

Even  if I add a "console.log(this.employees)" to print the values passed to the variable employees. The output is as follows

[image: The console output]

No where I can see the data passed to the variable. I'm expecting the following dateset passed from the back-end to be shown.

```
[{"id":34,"firstName":"Jade","lastName":"Mart","emailId":"jm18@gmail.com"},{"id":35,"firstName":"Patric","lastName":"Anderson","emailId":"patric@gmail.com"}]
```

But Nowhere it is shown in the console.log() output and the debugging process.But the data is correctly shows on the web page as shown above.

please help me to understand how to debug and see the data passed from the back-end.It is very helpful for me in the future developing work when doing more complex work.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

employees is an Observable, so you can't see directly the result.

You have a couple ways to do this, I will tell you two:

- In Chrome Dev Tools (or any other), you have a tab "Network" and you can see the request there.
- If you want something in your code directly, you can use rxjs map inside a pipe and do the console log in there.

Like these:

```
reloadData(){
    this.employees = this.employeeService.getEmployeesList().pipe(
        map( response => {
            console.log(response);
            //return the response value
            return response;
        })
    )
}
```